# How to mention other website as the Product or Service in other website's terms?

Tags: terms-of-service, legal-terms, website

Let's say I have a **Billing website(1st website)** for clients where a client makes an account and buys a plan.

Then what I do is create a **website(2nd website)** for that client's shop where his employees and his other customers register and use it.

So what I want to do is to say the following in the **terms of 1st website:**

**"the Product, the Services, the Website -> refers to both sites".**

Is it **legal** to do that ? If so how do I mention 2nd site as "the Product", "the Service" in the 1st site's terms.

Comment: Is it unclear what you think could be illegal? Please clarify. There is nothing wrong with establishing that some (or all) conditions apply to website A and website B.

Comment: ok. So it means I can mention the domain name of the other website e.g  "the Website" includes abc.com and xyz.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so how do I mention 2nd site as "the Product", "the Service" in the
>   1st site's terms.

In the Terms and Conditions of the Billing (or "first") website, you could start with a section for *Definitions*. There you establish the meaning of terms used throughout the contract.

It is up to you to define "*the Website*" as including abc.com and xyz.com, or to assign labels to each one. Just make sure the scope and meaning of your clauses are very specific, since the doctrine of [*contra proferentem*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contra_proferentem) is applicable in *contract law*.

Comment: Can you just give me an example for the Website definition including both websites ? I know for the Company definition - CompanyName LLC, contractors and all data sources and suppliers, (collectively “CompanyName”, “we”, “us” or “our)

Comment: @Raj For instance, see [https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service), where it defines "Stack Overflow" or "Network" as "*a set of related Internet sites and other applications for questions and answers, owned and operated by Stack Exchange, Inc. . ("Stack Overflow", "we" or "us"), a Delaware corporation*". There really is nothing special, you would only be establishing labels as Stack Exchange does for ease of reference in the rest of the contract.